# Python subprocess.popen from within a cron job

Tags: python, shell, cron, subprocess, qgis

I'm trying to setup a server to run on startup (Raspberry Pi) - the server calls a script which calls a script...except they're not firing.

1. add the cron job using `crontab -e` and writing `@reboot python3 /path/to/my_server.py` (also tested with `&` at end of line)...this works fine.
2. `my_server.py` uses `httpd.server_forever()` to listen at a few endpoints...this works fine.
3. One of the server endpoints runs `subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/path/to/my_script.py'])`.
4. `my_script.py` then runs `subprocess.Popen(['qgis'])` (also tried with `shell=True`).

However, `QGIS` isn't starting.

This is only happening when trying to run everything on boot with the cron job. If I manually open a terminal and run `python3 /path/to/my_server.py` then everything works as expected. I'm thinking it has to do with...things not being run in a shell/terminal - maybe a behavior of `Popen`?

Comment: You have to give absolute path to Python executable in cron, like `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @ipaleka That also applies to step 3?

Comment: I believe yes it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `QGIS` requires x server to be running, and `cron` won't have that by default.

Fix: change `cron` entry to be `@reboot export DISPLAY=:0; python3 /path/to/my_server.py` and everything works!

Comment: Note for QGIS: with the above setup plugins did not work...but that seems outside the scope of the question.